Ollama Status Code 404 Error when trying to run with LangChain
I am getting the following error when trying to run Ollama with LLama3 and invoking the model from LangChain (python)
langchain_community.llms.ollama.OllamaEndpointNotFoundError: Ollama call failed with status code 404. Maybe your model is not found and you should pull the model with `ollama pull llama3`.

Context:

Running on MacOs
Code:

from langchain_community.llms import Ollama

llm = Ollama(model="llama3", base_url="http://localhost:11434/")
llm.invoke("Why is the sky blue?")


Tried running Ollama as a service with ollama serve (It does not seem to make a difference)

I am able to see that Ollama is running on the localhost:11434

I am getting a 404 error when I try to access localhost:11434/llama3

ollama list shows llama 3 installed



I see the same error with both llama3 and llama2 on a Mac, OS 14.5, Ollama 0.1.41.

llm = ChatOllama(model=model, temperature=0.0)

I don't see this with other models such as mistral and Gemma

It works for me in Jupyter notebook when I set model="llama2"
llm = Ollama(model="llama2")


Remove the slash as below:
llm = Ollama(model="llama3", base_url="http://localhost:11434")


I did faced the same issue with both llama3 and llama2 on my Mac
Here is how it got resolved-

Remove the ending slash from the base URL param

llm = Ollama(model="llama3", base_url="http://localhost:11434")

Restart the Jupytar karnel.
Run all the cells again.

